# declaration of a variable

Tags: sql-server, variables

I have a table with 2 columns ID(identity), errormessage (10 possible error messages)

now I have certain business logics from where I can get the possible error messages if any.
I have 10 SPs for that. I want all the error messages in the column2 = error message.

according to the logic that I am using, it is updating only the last updated error (not all)
lets say for business logic1 (by executing sp1) for ID = 1 i get errorMsg = `<Data Invalid>`
for ID = 1, executing SP2, I am getting `<Data Corrupted>`

Now, I want to get both messages in one column.
I know it's difficult to interpret (since I have 10 SPs) please help me in the approach I should use.

PS: I have declared a variable for each error message in SPs and adding the next message into it, but it is showing the error even if that error did not occor. For example:

```
declare @errormessage1 varchar(20)
set @errormessage1 = <Data Invalid>  

declare @errormessage2 varchar(20)
set @errormessage2 = <Data corrupted>

update my_table
set errormessage= @errormessage1 + @errormessage2
from my_table
```

even if errormessage1 does not have invalid data, it is still showing me in col2 =  + 
now, problem here is it should show only the actual error not (all declared errors)

Thanks

Comment: You have a table with a list of 10 possible error messages and their ids. You could have all 10 messages generated for a given call. The desire is to have all of the error messages returned in a single column (and row).  Is this an accurate interpretation of what you are asking?

Comment: @billinkc: Yes, That is correct.

Comment: We can assume there are 10 variables with the appropriate error message in them. How does the stored procedure factor in to this? I assume it determines whether a business rule has been violated? What does the signature of the procs look like?

Answer (score 0):

Some wild guesses here while we wait for more details

```
-- Create a local table variables to hold processing results
DECLARE @PROCESSING_RESULTS
(
   -- size and type these accurately
   id int NOT NULL
,  error_message varchar(8000)
)
DECLARE @ID int
,  @error_message varchar(8000)

-- Load up the table 
-- Not sure what the signature of the proc looks like so guessing here
-- Either use an insert into with the execute
-- This assumes an invocation of the proc returns a result set 
INSERT INTO
    @PROCESSING_RESULTS
EXECUTE dbo.SP1 @id = 1


-- This approach assumes output parameters
EXECUTE dbo.SP1 @id = 1, @error_message output
INSERT INTO
    @PROCESSING_RESULTS
([id], error_message)
SELECT 1, @error_message

-- Repeat the above approach for all 10 procs

-- At this point, all the errors are in our processing_results table
-- so we should do something with them.
-- Assuming you want a CSV list of all the error messages, this will
-- mash all the results 
SELECT STUFF(
 (SELECT ',' + PR.error_message
FROM @PROCESSING_RESULTS PR
ORDER BY PR.error_message
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
```